# How can an advanced civilization help another to overcome the first challenges of the space age?

Tags: civilization, communication

An advanced civilization, like ours could be in a couple of hundred years, realized that the most challenging time in their history was when they had the knowledge to make global changes, but not the wisdom to see the consequences of their actions. (In our history this is the time from the beginning of the 20th century to the end of the 21th century. WW1 and WW2, cold war, terrorism, global warming, population explosion leading to famines and pandemics, etc.) They want to help others to overcome these difficult times.

But how can they do it?

Sending high power radio signals to every habitable planet, for millions of years continuously, is not an option, because it is just another form of pollution. Listening to, and answering, radio signals is difficult, because the answer may reach those emerging civilizations too late, if they are not within a 50 light-year radius of one of the automatic answering stations.

Comment: Upvoted because I want to see ideas about how our civilization can help another without actually contacting or interacting with the civilization that we want to help.  A thorny problem to be sure!  In real life, a solution to this problem might be applied to first world governments who want to help third world people under similar circumstances.

Comment: *"Sending high power radio signals to every habitable planet, for millions of years continuously, is not an option, because it is just another form of pollution":* That is rather stretching the definition of *pollution* way beyond the breaking point. Our very own Sun pollutes the electromagnetic spectrum billions of billions of billions of times more than a feeble signal coming a tiny planet revolving around a distant star.

Comment: And anyway, all they can do is tell other developing worlds the story of their history. It's not as if our distant descendents, however advanced they might be, will be endowed with the a perfect divine knowledge of good and evil. Tell the newly discovered developing worlds the history of this most admirable advanced civilization, tell it honestly, and let them decide what to do with it. The Prime Directive is there for a reason; as history teaches us, attempts to force lesser nations to adopt the solutions which worked oh so well for their oh so civilized betters often end in tears.

Comment: @AlexP 1. The signal might be feeble at the receiver's end, but quite strong near the transmitter. 2. Sending signals to all habitable planets of all the solar systems of all the universe requires a bit more energy than the Sun. 3. Radio astronomers are not too happy about the emission of the Sun either. Radio astronomers of another world would be even less happy to hear that someone wants to build an even more powerful transmitter at their backyard, for a purely alturistic purpose.

Answer (score 1):

They could send out stores of wisdom, eg. in the form of black rectangular monuments, which are programmed to divulge their data when they sense a proper level of development. Be it via detection of radio waves, or by putting the slab on the moon, for example.

In seriousness, the proper way to leave info to many civilizations across time and space is to send out von-Neumann probes, self replicating machines which spread across the whole galaxy within only a few hundred housand years, leaving one of their own in all habitable systems.

That's not the hard part. The hard part is to select the information to leave to other, unknown civilizations so that you can expect to do more good than harm with it.

Answer (score 1):

Because the question is broad, Id like to expand on the issues, first.  Without that, its not easy to decide how to outline how to develop it further, and what you might need to consider.

You have 5 problems in one, really:

- **a communication problem** - what kind of message/s or approaches would be either universal, comprehensible or interpretable?
- **a search problem** - how do we know where best to send it? Space is vast.
- **a technical problem** - if we knew what to say, show, or do, how would we physically accomplish it?
- **a social/cultural problem** - assuming our efforts reach a different world, how on earth can we know what would be relevant to them? How do we ensure we are believed? How do we minimise the chances of an inappropriate approach breaching important cultural values/taboos?  *(Nobody on earth likes to be told by dodgy unknown outsiders that all their awesome vaunted progress is just wrong, look at climate and environment and any number of coverups and conspiracy theorists! Why expect different elsewhere?)*
- **an ethics problem** - if we can do all these, should we? Will we give them knowledge that does harm because they didn't have to take steps on the way? Are we depriving them of experiences as a society that they actually need?

The question focuses on the technical and search issues,  how, physically, to do it, and where to send it. But I'm not sure even with those 2 answered, that its solved.

Apologies for a non answer, but this was a bit too long for a comment. If the question is updated I'll have a go at a more specific solution.

Comment: I'd split 4, into 3 separate bullets - 1) knowing what is relevant.  2) a problem related to "will this be believed and taken seriously or shrugged aside as aliens without a clue". 3) a social/cultural problem related to their social needs for communication